# How to graph a sphere with cartesian equations?

Tags: plotting

I'm new to Mathematica and I need to ask how to graph a sphere, cylinder, etc.. using cartesian equations.

For example in sphere's case $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

I tried to use `Plot3D` but it doesn't work..

Comment: Mathematica's help docs are generally going to be your #1 resource. Click on `Plot3D`, hit F1, and within a click or two you will find `RegionPlot3D` and other related functions (by following the "see also" links at the bottom).

Answer (score 15):

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

or

```
RegionPlot3D[Norm[{x, y, z}] <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

**Edit**
All together now!

```
opt = {Mesh -> False, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False};
Show[
 RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
              Evaluate@opt, PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow]], 
 RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
              Evaluate@opt, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Or `ContourPlot3D[ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]`

Comment: @belisarius: Using `RegionPlot3D` gives the "solid sphere", a 3-manifold, whereas the OP asked for the spherical surface, a 2-manifold, and that's what `ContourPlot3D` gives. (Not that one would see much difference graphically--unless one began slicing into the object.)

Comment: @murray Thanks. I'm aware of that, but as the OP asked for a "graph" and not for a mathematical description of the surface, I think the result is ["almost but not quite .."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Not_entirely_unlike)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use trig to get the {x,y,z} coordinates, the same as the spherical coordinates formulas:

```
f[u_,v_]:= {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}
ParametricPlot3D[f[u,v],{u,0,2π},{v,0,π}]
```

So x = Cos[u] Sin[v], y = Sin[u] Sin[v], and z = Cos[v].
You can put styles in afterwards, like transparency, color, mesh, etc.
[image: picture of sphere]